# Extraer datos de Api

Tags: javascript

compañeros me encuentro batallando con los objetos de una api no puedo acceder a ella, recurro a ustedes, ya me salvaron muchas veces de las cuales me encuentro agradecido. les dejo mi codigo en el cual estoy trabajando:

```js
  document.querySelector('.ranking').innerHTML += '<p style="color:rgba(105, 109, 
 115,0.465);">Prueba...</p>';
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pokemon-go-api/pokemon-go-api/gh-pages/api/raidboss.json';
request.open("GET", url);
 request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
const posts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
posts.forEach((post) => {
  if (post.currentList == "mega") { 
    document.getElementById("raid1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <div class="ranking_item">
    <div class=""ranking_img ${post.currentList.mega[6].types[0]}"">
    
    <img src="${post.currentList.mega[3].assets[0].image}">
    <img  src=${post.currentList.mega[5].shiny ? "assets/img/icon/shiny_white.png" : "assets/img/icon/no-shiny-icon.png"} alt="shiny">
        <div class="ranking_name">
        <span>${post.currentList.mega[4].names.Spanish}</span>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="ranking_info">
    <div class="ranking_name" style="display: none;">
    
    </div>
   
    <span>PC Potenciado</span>
    
    <p>${post.currentList.mega[9].cpRangeBoost[0]}</p>
    <p>${post.currentList.mega[9].cpRangeBoost[1]}</p>
    <span>PC Normal</span>
    <p>${post.currentList.mega[9].cpRange[0]}</p>
    <p>${post.currentList.mega[9].cpRange[1]}</p>
    </div>`
    
    );
  }

});
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="ranking">
   <div  class="ranking_block" id="raid1"></div>
  </div>
```

intente de varias formas, sin resultado alguno, no puedo obtener los resultados de la api y mostrarlo en mi html.

espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano gracias (edite) el link para extraer los datos, sigue sin funcionar :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema no es que no podes acceder a la API, porque estás accediendo correctamente, sino que te devuelve un `Object` y lo manejas como un `Array`.

[image: Fetched Object]

Viendo que únicamente utilizabas la propiedad `mega` y es un `Array`, si cambias `posts.forEach` por `posts.currentList.mega.forEach` ya te queda iterando sobre el Array `mega`.

De ahí en adelante es simplemente tener en cuenta que ya estamos dentro de mega y cambiar los `post.currentList.mega[6]` por `post`, que sería cada item iterado. Yo lo nombré `Item` porque veía mucho `post`, pero te dejo el resultado de la función.

```
posts.currentList.mega.forEach(item => {
   document.getElementById("raid1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
   <div class="ranking_item">
   <div class=""ranking_img ${item.types[0]}"">
   
   <img src="${item.assets.image}">
   <img  src=${item.shiny ? "assets/img/icon/shiny_white.png" : "assets/img/icon/no-shiny-icon.png"} alt="shiny">
       <div class="ranking_name">
       <span>${item.names.Spanish}</span>
       </div>
       
   </div>
   <div class="ranking_info">
   <div class="ranking_name" style="display: none;">
   
   </div>
  
   <span>PC Potenciado</span>
   
   <p>${item.cpRangeBoost[0]}</p>
   <p>${item.cpRangeBoost[1]}</p>
   <span>PC Normal</span>
   <p>${item.cpRange[0]}</p>
   <p>${item.cpRange[1]}</p>
   </div>`
   );
})
```

Y no sé si es el resultado que esperabas, pero me renderiza lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: genial, muchas gracias, edito mi respuesta por que ya logre acceder. que tengas un buen dia

Comment: me ayudarían con esto:  

  ${item.types.map(t => '<div><img src="'+ t.types +'"></div>')}

intento acceder a: 

"types": [
                    "Normal",
                    "Flying"
                ]

y estoy obteniendo como resultado:

<div><img src="undefined"></div>
,
<div><img src="undefined"></div>

como podría hacer para obtener el nombre y convertirlo en imagen y evitar que salga la coma (,)